# Error while loading string to xml document in windows c#

Tags: c#, windows, file, xmldocument

I have an application where it reads the xml data, makes some changes and saves it into a word document. When i run the app 1st time the base URI is  "C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug". But when i run the second time without restarting the app the base URI changes to last saved location ans i get an error saying the xml file not found.Below is the part of code. Where am i gng wrong

```
 string xmlSource = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlSource))

                xmlSource = "Dictionary.xml";

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(xmlSource);
                FileStream usrFs = null;
            try
            {

                usrFs = new FileStream(xmlSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                 FileShare.ReadWrite);

            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {

                doc.Load(usrFs);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path rather than relative path.

```
xmlSource = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Dictionary.xml";
```